# Lazy loader, alternative to cglib?

Tags: java, javassist, cglib

With cglib I can create a lazily instantiated BigInteger using this code:

```
Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
enhancer.setSuperclass(BigInteger.class);
enhancer.setCallback(
        new LazyLoader() {

            @Override
            public Object loadObject() throws Exception {
                // expensive computation here
                long totalCount = getTotalCount(totalCountExecutors); 
                return BigInteger.valueOf(totalCount);
            }
        });
totalCount =
        (BigInteger)
                enhancer.create(new Class[] {String.class}, new Object[] {"0"});
```

However the above throws warnings with Java 11 and there does not seem to be compatible release in the making, so I'd like to migrate to other libraries.
ByteBuddy is ... massive, and would like to avoid such a big dependency. Is it possible to create a lazy loading proxy with javassist (or any other "light" library) instead?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can create objects lazily without going to proxies and class loading, especially given that you have lambdas, e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-with-java-8

Comment: @zapl probably because they need to pass a lazily loaded object of a certain type to a library.

Comment: @ohlec ok, but proxies aren't magic that you can't recreate with normal code (unless they do things not allowed by compilers), e.g. https://ideone.com/XK2GOH

Comment: I have a BigDecimal that is expensive to compute and that not all subequent steps in the code will use (depends on too many factor). BigDecimal does not have a no-arg constructor so a common proxy is not an option. Oh, but I see you're not using a Java proxy, but making a subclass instead... could work.

Comment: @zapl that is basically a manually created proxy. Sure, it's possible, but it needs a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @ohlec yes, you'll have to generate that class yourself but it's also just a few keystrokes to add overrides for all methods, then search & replace all `super.` with `delegate.get()` in the example. - @andrea-aime just like your current solution where a similar subclass is generated at runtime (you also use the `super("0")` constructor via `new Object[] {"0"}`). Besides less code, that also has advantages like it will override methods that don't exist yet in the current java version, although your code is also very unlikely to use them.

Comment: Which code will be using the lazy BigInteger? If it's your own code, you should reconsider/refactor it.

Comment: The code using is my own, but the bean containing it is not.

Comment: @zapl I'd turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the implementation without any third-party library at all as @zapl suggested. Took me 3 minutes to create this in Eclispe: I created a class stub, then used 'Generate Delegate Methods...' and then 'Generate Getters and Setters...'. All kudos go to @zapl.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class MyBigInt extends BigInteger {

    private BigInteger delegate;

    public MyBigInt() {
        super("0");
    }

    private BigInteger getDelegate() {
        if (delegate == null) {
            delegate = computeMeHere();
        }
        return delegate;
    }

    public byte byteValue() {
        return getDelegate().byteValue();
    }

    public short shortValue() {
        return getDelegate().shortValue();
    }

    public BigInteger nextProbablePrime() {
        return getDelegate().nextProbablePrime();
    }

    public BigInteger add(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().add(val);
    }

    public BigInteger subtract(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().subtract(val);
    }

    public BigInteger multiply(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().multiply(val);
    }

    public BigInteger divide(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().divide(val);
    }

    public BigInteger[] divideAndRemainder(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().divideAndRemainder(val);
    }

    public BigInteger remainder(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().remainder(val);
    }

    public BigInteger pow(int exponent) {
        return getDelegate().pow(exponent);
    }

    public BigInteger gcd(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().gcd(val);
    }

    public BigInteger abs() {
        return getDelegate().abs();
    }

    public BigInteger negate() {
        return getDelegate().negate();
    }

    public int signum() {
        return getDelegate().signum();
    }

    public BigInteger mod(BigInteger m) {
        return getDelegate().mod(m);
    }

    public BigInteger modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m) {
        return getDelegate().modPow(exponent, m);
    }

    public BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger m) {
        return getDelegate().modInverse(m);
    }

    public BigInteger shiftLeft(int n) {
        return getDelegate().shiftLeft(n);
    }

    public BigInteger shiftRight(int n) {
        return getDelegate().shiftRight(n);
    }

    public BigInteger and(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().and(val);
    }

    public BigInteger or(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().or(val);
    }

    public BigInteger xor(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().xor(val);
    }

    public BigInteger not() {
        return getDelegate().not();
    }

    public BigInteger andNot(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().andNot(val);
    }

    public boolean testBit(int n) {
        return getDelegate().testBit(n);
    }

    public BigInteger setBit(int n) {
        return getDelegate().setBit(n);
    }

    public BigInteger clearBit(int n) {
        return getDelegate().clearBit(n);
    }

    public BigInteger flipBit(int n) {
        return getDelegate().flipBit(n);
    }

    public int getLowestSetBit() {
        return getDelegate().getLowestSetBit();
    }

    public int bitLength() {
        return getDelegate().bitLength();
    }

    public int bitCount() {
        return getDelegate().bitCount();
    }

    public boolean isProbablePrime(int certainty) {
        return getDelegate().isProbablePrime(certainty);
    }

    public int compareTo(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().compareTo(val);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x) {
        return getDelegate().equals(x);
    }

    public BigInteger min(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().min(val);
    }

    public BigInteger max(BigInteger val) {
        return getDelegate().max(val);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getDelegate().hashCode();
    }

    public String toString(int radix) {
        return getDelegate().toString(radix);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getDelegate().toString();
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray() {
        return getDelegate().toByteArray();
    }

    public int intValue() {
        return getDelegate().intValue();
    }

    public long longValue() {
        return getDelegate().longValue();
    }

    public float floatValue() {
        return getDelegate().floatValue();
    }

    public double doubleValue() {
        return getDelegate().doubleValue();
    }

    public long longValueExact() {
        return getDelegate().longValueExact();
    }

    public int intValueExact() {
        return getDelegate().intValueExact();
    }

    public short shortValueExact() {
        return getDelegate().shortValueExact();
    }

    public byte byteValueExact() {
        return getDelegate().byteValueExact();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end this is the best match to what I was looking for, no extra library baggage.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy with Byte Buddy but if you must use a "lightweight" (my connection downloads 3 MB in less then 100 milliseconds) this is how you would do it:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory .setSuperclass(BigInteger.class);
factory .setFilter(new MethodFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean isHandled(Method m) {
     return !m.getName().equals("finalize");
  }
});

Class<?> clazz = factory.createClass();
MethodHandler handler = new MethodHandler() {

  private volatile Object delegate;

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object self, Method method, Method proceed,
                       Object[] args) throws Throwable {
     Object delegate = this.delegate;
     if (delegate == null) {
       synchronized (this) {
         delegate = this.delegate;
         if (delegate == null) {
           this.delegate = delegate = loadObject();
         }
       }
     }
     return method.invoke(delegate, args);
 }

  private Object loadObject() throws Exception {
    // expensive computation here
    long totalCount = getTotalCount(totalCountExecutors); 
    return BigInteger.valueOf(totalCount);
  }
};

BigInteger instance = (BigInteger) clazz.newInstance();
((Proxy) instance).setHandler(handler);
```

Do however note that Javassist is facing its own issues with the module system and you might need another migration some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Javassist** library (http://www.javassist.org) ?

For instance, **Hibernate** is intensively using Javassist proxies to manage lazy loading:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/proxy/pojo/javassist/JavassistLazyInitializer.html

You might inspire from them ?

Comment: You might be onto something, but the code seems to be heavily dependent on Hibernate, which I don't have in the classpath.

Comment: I just meant this: do not use it as such but take a look on how Hibernate is doing it (using javassist), and try to do the same (but without embedding Hibernate of course)...

Comment: What I really mean is that 100 reward points should be worth more than a generic pointer that maybe could help ;-)

Comment: Just FYI: Hibernate is using Byte Buddy for a while.